# Select all elements inside sibling elements except the hovered element only on a hover

Tags: css

I want to select the anchor elements in all the .col-md-4 elements in my .blog-grid element when I hover over one of the anchor elements. I also don't want to select the element I am hovering over. Below is my attempt to do this, but it is not working. Any suggestions? I prefer to stick with just css unless javascript is necessary.

```
.blog-grid .col-md-4:not(.col-md-4 a:hover) a {
    opacity:.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier to setup the demo, I have changed your example to a similar one:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwe6V/)